# Размер классов при наследовании в С++

Tags: c++, классы, выравнивание

Если создать 2 таких класса:

```
class A
{
    double a;
    double b;
};

class B : public A
{
    char a;
};
```

и взять `sizeof(B)`, то получим 24.

Eсли добавить в класс А поле типа int, то `sizeof(B)` будет так же равен 24 (такой же результат будет если в классе B заменить char на int)

```
class A
{
    double a;
    double b;
    int c;
};

class B : public A
{
    char a;
};
```

Почему в этих 2 случаях размер класса в байтах совпадает?

Компилятор gcc.

PS: с компилятором от студии выдает 32 байта

Comment: Размер выравнивается по максимальному размеру поля. Т.е. по размеру double. Это 8 байт. https://habr.com/ru/post/142662/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к наследованию. В тех же реализациях вы получите тот же самый результат в случаях

```
struct A1
{
  double a;
  double b;
  char c;
};

struct A2
{
  double a;
  double b;
  int c;
  char d;
};
```

Оба класса будут иметь размер 24.

Требования выравнивания самого большого из использованных типов `double` (выравнивание на `8`) диктуют, что размер класса с двумя полями `double` и "еще чем-то" должен быть как минимум 24. А остальные поля, с их более слабыми требованиями выравнивания, просто помещаются в лишние байты этого размера. Пока они помещаются, размер расти не будет.

Такой класс тоже будет иметь размер 24

```
struct A3
{
  double a;
  double b;
  char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8;
};
```

Но если вы добавить в него еще хоть один `char`, то размер станет 32.